# How to update only tab title in p:tabView /p:accordion or similar component?

Tags: primefaces

I am trying to make the title of some tabs underlined if some specific content is shown on that tabs using ajax update (just titles, nothing else). Currently it works only if I refresh the page or the whole component (but it is bad idea because of many data loading from the database).

It is possible? I tried to get and update this component on the client side with jQuery (getting element by href) and from the bean (RequestConext.getCurrentInstance().update()), but unsuccessfully.

The generated html (styles are excluded):

```xml
<div id="m_tabview" style="display: block;" data-widget="m_tabviewWv">
  <ul role="tablist">
    <li role="tab" aria-expanded="true">
        <a href="#m_tabview:j_idt25">Basic information</a>
    </li>
    <li role="tab" aria-expanded="false">
        <a href="#m_tabview:documentsTab">
            <u>Documents</u>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li role="tab" aria-expanded="false">
        <a href="#m_tabview:j_idt191">Social data</a>
    </li>
    <li role="tab" aria-expanded="false">
        <a href="#m_tabview:contactsTab">
            Contacts
        </a>
    </li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

And there are two tabs have mutable titles: Documents (already underlined) and Contacts.

The XHTML code is like below:

```xml
<p:tabView id="m_tabview" widgetVar="m_tabviewWv" scrollable="false">
  <p:tab title="Basic information">
    <h:form id="base_form">
      <!-- Some form data with submit button -->
    </h:form>
  </p:tab>
  <p:tab id="documentsTab" name="documentsTab" title="#{clientform.documentsHeaderInline}">
    <h:form id="documents_form">
      <!-- Some form data with submit button -->
    </h:form>
  </p:tab>
  <p:tab title="Social data">
    <h:form id="social_data_form">
      <!-- Some form data with submit button -->
    </h:form>
  </p:tab>
  <p:tab id="contactsTab" title="#{clientform.contactsHeaderInline}">
    <h:form id="сontacts_form">
      <!-- Some form data with submit button -->
    </h:form>
  </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

When user press the "Save" button, backed bean `clientform` change titles if necessary and then I need to update them dynamically, but I don't know how.

Primefaces version is 4.0.6 and unfortunately cannot be updated at the moment.

Comment: Show the "Save" button. If you don't want to udpate whole `p:tab`/`p:tabView` then it have to be done with javascript I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update individual tabs since they do not have renderers in PrimeFaces. What you can try is to move the title to a `f:facet name="title"...`, put an `h:outputText id="tabIdTitle"...` and update that outputText when required. This is supported since PF 3.2. So something like

```xml
<p:tabView id="m_tabview" widgetVar="m_tabviewWv" scrollable="false">
  <p:tab title="Basic information">
    <h:form id="base_form">
      <!-- Some form data with submit button -->
    </h:form>
  </p:tab>
  <p:tab id="documentsTab" name="documentsTab">
    <f:facet name="title">
       <h:outputText id="documentsTabTitle" value="#{clientform.documentsHeaderInline}" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:form id="documents_form">
      <!-- Some form data with submit button -->
    </h:form>
  </p:tab>
  <p:tab title="Social data">
    <h:form id="social_data_form">
      <!-- Some form data with submit button -->
    </h:form>
  </p:tab>
  <p:tab id="contactsTab">
    <f:facet name="title">
      <h:outputText id="contactsTabTitle" value="#{clientform.contactsHeaderInline} "/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:form id="сontacts_form">
      <!-- Some form data with submit button -->
    </h:form>
  </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kukeltje and Geinmachi!

The right way is really to use a facet (but with CSS style separately because if you use CSS inline, the tags will be shown as is and text won't be underlined):

```
<p:tab id="documentsTab" name="documentsTab">
  <f:facet name="title">
    <h:outputText id="documentsTabTitle" value="Documents" style="#{clientform.documentsHeaderInline}"/>
  </f:facet>
...
</p:tab>
```

and (in managed bean if necessary):

```
documentsHeaderInline = "text-decoration: underline;";
```

Comment: And why not add this as a comment to my answer?

Comment: Hi Kukeltje. Your answer is not completely working for me - when I added
      <h:outputText>someText</h:outputText>
nothing have been shown on the screen. The right way is to use the value attribute of outputText tag. You had given me the right way.
If you don't agree with me - no problem, I can add the comment below.